# THREE.js merging particle system to mesh

Tags: three.js, particles

I'm currently experimenting in three.js and i have a mesh to which i'd like to attach a particle system (Engine effects on a space ship). I've been experimenting a LOT, but i'm completely lost. Could anyone please point me in the right direction to get it done? or some example would be great!

i've tried just merging the geometry of the particle system to the space ship using THREE.GeometryUtils.merge, but it doesnt work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. a particleSystem has local coordinates, constanly updating the position and rotation of the particlesystem to that of the ship works.

once an emitter is declared, you only have to set the position to that of the mesh it should be attached to like so:

```
particleEmitter.position = controlledMesh.position;
```

all that remains is setting the rotation, this does have to be updated every update:

```
function update(){
    particleEmitter.rotation = controlledMesh.rotation;
}
```

Comment: You should also be able to just attach the particle system to the mesh. Something like: yourMesh.add(yourParticleSystem). Then it's a child of the mesh, getting updated with the position and rotation of the parent. It's nicer to do it that way :)
And for the rest: You're on a good way. three.js has several particle examples. If there's something specific you want to know I'll gladly help.